# Why am I getting this error while importing mqtt module in App.js of my React app?

Tags: reactjs, mqtt, mqtt.js

I am getting this error at : import mqtt from 'mqtt'

```
ERROR
Buffer is not defined
ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at ./node_modules/mqtt-packet/constants.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39648:34)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:103411:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:102835:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:103068:21)
    at ./node_modules/mqtt-packet/parser.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39937:19)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:103411:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:102835:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:103068:21)
    at ./node_modules/mqtt-packet/mqtt.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39844:18)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:103411:31)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because [mqtt.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) is a node.js package, not a package for the browser. Just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt-browser instead.